# Contravariance with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-functions

I have a typical `clone()` pattern like:

```
class Base {
    virtual Base *clone() const;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    Derived *clone() override;
    // ^-- note the contravariant type!
};
```

Now I would like to do away with dumb pointers, so I'd like to replace the return type with `std::unique_ptr`:

```
class Base {
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const;
};

class Derived {
    virtual std::unique_ptr</* Can't be Derived here */> clone() const;
};
```

But `std::unique_ptr<Base>` is not a base of `std::unique_ptr<Derived>`, so the method can't return it. But there are other methods in `Derived` that need to call `clone()` and need to treat the result as `Derived` (which they can be certain there is).

Now `std::shared_ptr` at least has the `std::static_pointer_cast`. But that does not apply to unique_ptr. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Isn't it called covariance?

Comment: Just return `std::unique_ptr<Base>`. It's not as expressive, I know. But in my experience, the mere existence of co-variant return types is a surprise to programmers.

Comment: Imo `clone` should return a raw pointer. Consider when you'd want to have a `shared_ptr`, you'd have to write `std::shared_ptr<Derived> ptr{d.clone().release()};`, which doesn't make very much sense.

Comment: @PasserBy This is completely wrong for two separate reasons. First, raw pointers that own their resource are bad code smell in modern C++, barring rare cases where you are working with allocators or memory at a low level. Second, `shared_ptr` has a constructor from `unique_ptr` directly so that code is not necessary. `unique_ptr` is the simplest and most canonical heap-owning pointer; classes that want to take ownership of a heap object (like `shared_ptr`) should provide a constructor that takes it.

Comment: @NirFriedman Makes sense, but only because `unique_ptr` can be held as _the_ canonical heap owning pointer.